# Ext.NET ComboBox Databind from DataTable

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, combobox, ext.net

I have an ext.net v2.5 combobox and im trying to databind the combobox in server side onload the asocieted store with .net datatable but is not working.

Any ideas how these can be done. databinding datatable to combobox?

```
<ext:ComboBox  ID="ddlProduct" runat="server" ValueField="IDProduct"  DisplayField="ProductName" FieldLabel="Product" LabelWidth="50" Width="250">
                            <Store>
                                <ext:Store runat="server" ID="ddlProductStore">
                                    <Model>
                                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                                            <Fields>
                                                <ext:ModelField Name="IDProduct" />
                                                <ext:ModelField Name="ProductName" />
                                            </Fields>
                                        </ext:Model>
                                    </Model>
                                </ext:Store>
                            </Store>
                        </ext:ComboBox>
```

Server Side Code:

```
ddlProductStore.DataSource = MyApp.Data.DataRepository.Provider.ExecuteDataSet("sp_GetSegmentProducts ", 1).Tables(0)
        ddlProductStore.DataBind()
```

Comment: Keep on downvoting me Harold. Your days are numbered. Yeah, I know it's you. You have no class, you know that? You lazy bum. After your off-topic http://stackoverflow.com/q/36356995/ and seeing many of my Q&A's drop.

Comment: @Fred-ii, this is not an chatting site.. if have any thing to say about the post.. pleas let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears to be working well with a DataTable in the test below. So, I assume the DataTable on your side doesn't have required Columns.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!X.IsAjaxRequest)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();

            dataTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] {
                new DataColumn("IDProduct"),
                new DataColumn("ProductName")
            });

            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "id1", "Name1" });
            dataTable.Rows.Add(new object[] { "id2", "Name2" });

            this.ddlProductStore.DataSource = dataTable;
        }
    }
</script>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET v2 Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />

        <ext:ComboBox 
            runat="server" 
            ValueField="IDProduct" 
            DisplayField="ProductName" 
            FieldLabel="Product" 
            LabelWidth="50" 
            Width="250">
            <Store>
                <ext:Store ID="ddlProductStore" runat="server">
                    <Model>
                        <ext:Model runat="server">
                            <Fields>
                                <ext:ModelField Name="IDProduct" />
                                <ext:ModelField Name="ProductName" />
                            </Fields>
                        </ext:Model>
                    </Model>
                </ext:Store>
            </Store>
        </ext:ComboBox>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```